# bash: while read -r using <<< not working on macos

Tags: bash, date, while-loop

This script works perfectly well on Linux (bash), but trying to convert to Unix (MacOS) it's struggling.

```bash
while read -r key date
do
    age=$(gdate -d "$date" +%s)
    #do stuff with $key and $date
    # $key should be 'expiresOn' and $date should be eg '2024-03-02T00:00:00Z'

done <<<$(cat $file |grep expiresOn)
```

The output on MacOS is

```
gdate: invalid date ‘2024-03-02T00:00:00Z expiresOn: 2024-06-30T00:00:00Z expiresOn: 2024-07-01T00:00:00Z expiresOn: 2024-07-01T00:00:00Z expiresOn: 2024-05-30T00:00:00Z expiresOn: 2024-06-30T00:00:00Z’
```

From what I've read on other posts, `gdate` is used instead of `date`, but not sure if it's this or the `while read` that's causing issues.
I tried using `-d '\n'` among other delimiters but still not working.

Comment: You can always compare the output of the `gdate` in macOS and `date` in Linux to see the difference.

Comment: [UUOC](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award): `cat "$file" | grep expiresOn` = `grep expiresOn "$file"`. Depending on what you're doing inside the loop you may find that using GNU awk instead (untested: `gawk '/expiresOn/{key=$1; date=$2; age=mktime(gensub(/[^0-9]+/," ","g",date); ...}' "$file"`) executes orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Regarding "works perfectly well on Linux (bash), but trying to convert to Unix (MacOS)", that's apples an oranges and doesn't provide the information needed to help you. You should have said "works perfectly well on Linux (bash-version), but trying to convert to MacOS (foo-version)" where `foo` is whatever shell you're running on MaxOS (`zsh` by default but could be the ancient `bash` version that comes with MacOS or could be a newer bash version you installed) and `version` is whatever version of that shell you're running there (e.g. output of `echo "$BASH_VERSION"` if your shell is `bash`).

Comment: I respectfully disagree, @gilles-quénot understood and provided the accepted answer

Comment: @martyzee, yes, Gilles was able to propose an alternative that works for you in both places.  But he did not (and likely could not have done without guessing) explain why your original version *did not* work in both places.  That he was able to answer in no way conflicts with "Linux(bash)" and "Unix(MacOS)" being inapposite -- and that's something that's genuinely relevant to you.

Comment: Old versions of `bash` did not handle the combination of `read` and unquoted here-strings correctly. Known problems were fixed in 4.2 and 4.3, while you are likely using `bash` 3.2. Quoting the here string would fix the immediate problem,  but still not be the recommended solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another syntax:

```
while read -r key date
do
    age=$(gdate -d "$date" +%s)
    #do stuff with $key and $date
    # $key should be 'expiresOn' and $date should be eg '2024-03-02T00:00:00Z'

done < <(cat "$file" | grep expiresOn)
```

---

Process Substitution `>(command ...)` or `<(...)` is replaced by a temporary filename. Writing or reading that file causes bytes to get piped to the command inside. Often used in combination with file redirection: `cmd1 2> >(cmd2)`.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: Yes, and both ways. (Linux & MacOs)